# how to use html Code in gitHub Issue as part of message

Tags: github

I am Posting An Issue in gitHub 
I Want the users See my Html Code In message 
But Codes Are rendred
I have tried  and  and 
but it doesnt work , 
how can i set html as part of meesage in github ?
thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You could use a "[Fenced code blocks](https://help.github.com/articles/github-flavored-markdown#fenced-code-blocks)"

> Just wrap your code in ` (as shown below) and you won't need to indent it by four spaces.

````
```html
<my html code />
```
````

The HTML code won't be rendered, and the proper syntax highlighting will apply.